# VS Code auto change hex to decimal when I using console.log a buffer

Tags: node.js, buffer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SV0ux.jpg)Code:

```
  var buf = new Buffer.alloc(3,"56574842","hex");
    console.log(buf);
```

result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTMdr.jpg)Buffer(3) [86, 87, 72]

Why is not [56,57,48] ?

Comment: I get 56, 57, 48. What version of node are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My node version is v10.15.3. I think this problem just happen in VS Code.